# How to get ext.* variables into plugins block in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My build file looks like this:

```
val nexusBaseUri: String by extra
val gradle_version: String by extra
val kotlin_version: String by extra

buildscript {
    val nexusBaseUri by extra { "https://mynexusserver/nexus" }
    val gradle_version by extra { "4.1" }
    val kotlin_version by extra { "1.1.4-3" }
    val springBoot_version by extra { "2.0.0.M3" }

    repositories {
        maven { url = uri("$nexusBaseUri/repository/public") }
        jcenter()
        maven { url = uri("http://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
        maven { url = uri("http://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBoot_version")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version")
    }
}

plugins {
    application
    // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    // the following line causes a problem
    // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    kotlin("jvm", kotlin_version)
}

apply {
    plugin("kotlin-spring")
    plugin("org.springframework.boot")
    plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "eqip.fid.FdmlInterpreterDeveloperAppKt"
}

repositories {
    maven { url = uri("$nexusBaseUri/content/groups/public") }
    jcenter()
    maven { url = uri("http://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    maven { url = uri("http://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}

tasks {
    "wrapper"(Wrapper::class) {
        gradleVersion = gradle_version
    }
}
```

The error I get in IntelliJ IDEA is

> 'val kotlin_version: String' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary

How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot use variables in that section.

This question was asked already on stackoverflow with an answer, just wanted to put the answer here in case anyone else ran across it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37749402/559536

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53594357/3557894

Answer (score 4):

You can define a version inside `plugins` and then make this version accessible outside of the block, e.g. in the `dependencies` section.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm").version("1.1.61")
}

//This is necessary to make the version accessible in other places
val kotlinVersion: String? by extra {
    buildscript.configurations["classpath"]
            .resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies
            .find { it.moduleName == "kotlin-gradle-plugin" }?.moduleVersion
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib", kotlinVersion))
}
```

for version 1.2+, you will have to replace with `kotlin-gradle-plugin` `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin`

Comment: looks great, but returns `null` for me :/

Comment: @Xerus what version are you using?

Comment: 1.2.20, the most recent version. The moduleName now seems to be `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin` - when I use that it works again

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some tests around defining properties inside and outside the project buildscript block and it doesn't seem to work. The working and recommended solution if you want to have access to dependency-related properties is defining a buildSrc module ([check this github repo](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/tree/master/samples/project-with-buildSrc)) and then adding a Kotlin File/Class with the desired properties (versions, strings...). Something like:

```
object Dependency {

    object Foundation {

        const val KOTLIN = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${Version.Global.KOTLIN}"
        const val RANDOM_VERSION = "1.2.3"
    }
```

You could have access to anything declared in your buildSrc module because components declared in there are resolved during the Initialization phase if I'm not mistaken. Usage example as it follows:

```
plugins {
    val kotlin = Dependency.Foundation.KOTLIN
    kotlin("kapt").version(Dependency.Foundation.RANDOM_VERSION)
}
```

More info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources).