# Can't use project extra properties in plugin block

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multi-project build, and more often than not I find myself locking versions for artifacts across the board. So in my root project I define something like:

```kotlin
project.extra.set("pkgVersions", mapOf(
    "kotlin" to "1.2.0",
    "jooq" to "3.10.2"
))

val pkgVersions : Map<String, String> by project.extra

plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.0" apply false
}
```

While I can use `pkgVersions` anywhere, including other subprojects:

```kotlin
val pkgVersions by rootProject.extra

jooq {
    version = pkgVersions["jooq"]
}
```

I am not able to do so inside a plugin block:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version pkgVersions["kotlin"]
}
```

Gives me the error "pkgVersions can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if required". I am assuming this is because the implicit receiver should probably be the file's JVM impression? But instead it is using `PluginDependencySpec`. Trying an auto-complete with `this@` shows only `this@plugin`. This is just a long-shot guess from me. But, any pointers on what I am supposed to do?

Also, while we are at it, is there a way to create a **global type** in `gradle-kotlin-dsl`, for instance:

```kotlin
data class MyBuildType(..)
```

and have it available everywhere WITHOUT using `buildSrc`? It's pretty straightforward with `buildSrc` and I don't mind using it, but just wondering.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apparently this has become possible recently, if it wasn't possible in the past. (Almost) from the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management):

`gradle.properties`:

```
helloPluginVersion=1.0.0
```

`settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
  val helloPluginVersion: String by settings
  plugins {
    id("com.example.hello") version helloPluginVersion
  }
}
```

And now the docs say that `build.gradle.kts` should be empty but my testing shows that you still need this in `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("com.example.hello")
}
```

The version is now determined by `settings.gradle.kts` and hence by `gradle.properties` which is what we want...

Comment: No matter what I try I cannot get this to work.  Gradle makes me want to sling my computer out the window - I spend more time fixing gradle rubbish than programming these days ...

Comment: I hear you. In my experience this is true of a lot of the Java tool chain. Also Intellij. Too much magic...

Comment: In retrospect it was a bit of a rant, but honestly the build toolchain should be an implementation detail - not something that you should spend hours fixing, or changing because of breaking changes and deprecations in gradle .. wait, this turned into a rant again... Yes, far too much magic, which I'm not against as long as its robust! Which sadly I find gradle lacking.

Comment: see also reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management

Comment: Thank your for this answer!

Answer (score 10):

According to [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) (see **Constrained syntax** subsection)

> «plugin version» and «plugin id» must be constant, literal, strings

There are some other notes related to your question in the following paragraphs:

> The plugins {} block must also be a top level statement in the buildscript. It cannot be nested inside another construct (e.g. an if-statement or for-loop).
>
> **Can only be used in build scripts**
>
> The plugins {} block can currently only be used in a project’s build script. It cannot be used in script plugins, the settings.gradle file or init scripts.
>
> *Future versions of Gradle will remove this restriction.*

So it is not possible to do this now.

There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47507441/942565) to extract the plugin version and use it afterwards, but I personally find it ugly and prefer using explicit versions.