# How to use plugin version from gradle.properties in Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Now I use this way:

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion: String by project
    val springBootPluginVersion: String by project
    val springDependencyManagementPluginVersion: String by project

    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.springframework.boot") version springBootPluginVersion
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version springDependencyManagementPluginVersion
}
```

This variant compiles and works, but I don't know is this way right and why IntelliJ IDEA shows error on lines where placed versions definitions:

```
'val Build_gradle.project: Project' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Cross-post: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63369220/345716))

Apparently this has become possible recently, if it wasn't possible in the past. (Almost) from the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management):

`gradle.properties`:

```
helloPluginVersion=1.0.0
```

`settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
  val helloPluginVersion: String by settings
  plugins {
    id("com.example.hello") version helloPluginVersion
  }
}
```

And now the docs say that `build.gradle.kts` should be empty but my testing shows that you still need this in `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("com.example.hello")
}
```

The version is now determined by `settings.gradle.kts` and hence by `gradle.properties` which is what we want...

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple issues that have some details around this:

- [gradle/kotlin-dsl#480](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/480)
- [gradle/gradle#1697](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1697)

The way to do this in the most recent verions of Gradle is to use `settings.gradle` or `settings.gradle.kts` and the `pluginManagement {}` block.

In your case, it could look like:

```
pluginManagement {
  resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
      when (requested.id.id) {
        "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" -> {
          val kotlinVersion: String by settings
          useVersion(kotlinVersion)
        }
        "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" -> {
          val kotlinVersion: String by settings
          useVersion(kotlinVersion)
        }
        "org.springframework.boot" -> {
          val springBootPluginVersion: String by settings
          useVersion(springBootPluginVersion)
        }
        "io.spring.dependency-management" -> {
          val springDependencyManagementPluginVersion: String by settings
          useVersion(springDependencyManagementPluginVersion)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This code seems verbose, but probably this is better than define variable for each plugin in each module.

Comment: I have used this approach with some modifications, see https://github.com/rkudryashov/microservices-example